# Opening .dat and .key files in the Eclipse environment

Tags: java, eclipse, file

I'm working with a file system in Eclipse that includes .dat and .key files and would really like to be able to read them in the environment rather than keep an Emacs or Sublime window open on the side to read them.  Does anyone know of a package to install in Eclipse that will allow them to be read?

Thanks!

Comment: File extensions mean nothing, *especially* `.dat`. What are the formats of the files' contents?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created (text) files named with .dat and .key extensions, and Eclipse would open them in its internal editor with no fuss. However, if it's not doing that for you, right-click the file from the Project Explorer, and select the editor of your choice from the 'Open With' submenu. If your files are not some kind of text format there's a [hex editor plugin](http://ehep.sourceforge.net/) for Eclipse too.